# How to update Object's properties

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently learning Flutter / Dart and making good progress so please bear with me if this is a noob question.

I have an object.

```
class Todo {
  bool complete;
  String note;
}
```

According to user interactions, its properties will update.
Finally I get the latest state to do something.
I got two solutions:

1. Init the Todo once, then change properties every time.

```
final Todo todo = Todo();

todo.complete = true;
todo.note = "something";
```

2. Create a new Todo every time.

```
class Todo {
  Todo({this.complete = false, this.note = ""});
  final bool complete;
  final String note;
  Todo copyWith({bool complete, String note}) {
    return Todo(
      complete: complete ?? this.complete,
      note: note ?? this.note,
    );
  }
}
----------
final Todo todo = Todo();

final Todo2 = todo.copyWith(complete: true);
final Todo3 = todo.copyWith(note: "something");
```

In solution 1, I finally get todo.
In solution 2, I finally get todo3.

Which solution is better?

Thank you!

Comment: This is essentially the debate between mutable vs. immutable state. There is no better option. Just the one best suited for your purposes and which one you personally like more.

Comment: The difference is precisely as described in your question. Mutable state means you keep the same object but change the properties through accessors. Immutable state means you create a new object with the same and/or different data. There are pros and cons to each, and neither is objectively the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you need depends entirely on your use-case. The first sample you've provided has null as the Object's default properties, while the second sample has false as the default boolean and an empty String for the other.